# Why the output of cat.setName = setName and setName.apply pig, ['Babe'] is same. Even why It is neccessary to have them in code

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Hello everyone as I am new to coffee script so I have a confusion in this. I am following a book which is "https://www.montecassino.org/images/data/attachments/0000/0014/CoffeeScript.pdf" in which there is an example of code which is as following

```
setName = (name) -> 
    @name = name
    console.log(@name)
    console.log(name)

cat = {}
cat.setName = setName
cat.setName "Manu"
console.log(cat.name)

pig = {}
setName.apply pig, ['Babe']
console.log(pig.name)
```

In above code I dont understand whats going on. There is a function which is assigning name to objects. but what is the purpose and meaning of cat.setName = setName and setName.apply pig, ['Babe']. These lines have same meaning then what is difference between them. I am sorry if I am asking a silly question but I am completely confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both snippets--the one about the `cat` and the one about the `pig`--are accomplishing the same thing. They're invoking the `setName` function for two different objects. The difference is that in the `cat` example, the `setName` function becomes part of the `cat` object, and in the `pig` example, the `setName` function is applied to `pig`, but doesn't actually become part of the `pig` object.

It might be clearer to understand if you break it down into pieces and reason about what each piece is doing.

The first part defines a function, referred to by `setName`:

```
setName = (name) -> 
  @name = name
  console.log(@name)
  console.log(name)
```

As you can see, it takes a single parameter, `name`. `@name = name` may be a little confusing if you're not familiar with CoffeeScript. The `@` symbol in CoffeeScript is equivalent to `this` in JavaScript. In JS, it would be `this.name`, but in CS the shortcut is `@name`. When the `setName` function is called, `@` (or `this`) will refer to the context from which the `setName` function is called.

```
cat = {}
cat.setName = setName
cat.setName "Manu"
console.log(cat.name)
```

In the block above, first an empty object called `cat` is created. It initially has no functions or properties. Then we add the `setName` function to it, which was defined above.

This could have been written as:

```
cat = {}
cat.setName = (name) ->
  @name = name
  console.log(@name)
  console.log(name)
```

But since the `setName` function was already defined, we can simply set `cat.setName` to it.

When `cat.setName "Manu"` is called (alternatively written as `cat.setName("Manu")`, parenthesis in CoffeeScript are optional), `@` inside `setName` refers to the object that `setName` belongs to. `setName` is (appropriately) setting a property called `name` on the `cat` object. If you were to `console.log(cat)`, you'd see something like this:

```
{ setName: [Function], name: 'Manu' }
```

We took an empty object called `cat`, then gave it a function called `setName`, then called `setName`, which set a property on it: `name`.

The `pig` example has the same outcome, but the syntax is a little different:

```
pig = {}
setName.apply pig, ['Babe']
console.log(pig.name)
```

In this example, we call the `apply` function on `setName` (which is a function itself). Calling `setName.apply pig, ['Babe']` will *apply* the function `setName` to the object `pig`, with an array of arguments. By passing `pig` as the first parameter to `apply`, we're essentially telling `apply`: Inside of `setName`, whenever you see `@`, we're really talking about `pig`.

The second parameter for `apply` is an array of arguments to use when calling `setName`. There's only one element in this array, which matches the number of parameters that `setName` accepts. `['Babe']` is an argument array with just one argument: `'Babe'`.

The important difference between this and the `cat` example is that we didn't make `setName` part of the `pig` object. Indeed, `console.log(pig)` produces

```
{ name: 'Babe' }
```

See? No `setName` function. We only applied that function to the `pig` object. You notice in the cat example the line `cat.setName = setName`--we didn't do that for the `pig`.

You can see Mozilla's documentation of the `apply` JS function for some more background: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fapply

For what it's worth, I haven't often seen examples of `apply` being used in production CoffeeScript code. If you're getting really stuck on understanding that, it'll probably be worth it to move on and revisit it later.

Comment: Thanks a ton @sleeper2173. I have spent about 10 hours to understand this concept but I wasn't able to do so. At last I got it. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to hear it @Mandeep. Enjoy working with CoffeeScript